# How do you instruct Solve to use assumptions?

Tags: equation-solving

We know from special relativity that:$$E^2=m_0^2c^2+p^2c^4$$Where $E$ is the energy, $m_0$ is the rest mass, $c$ is the speed of light and $p$ is the momentum.  I want an expression for $E$.  I can tell by inspection that this is going to be $$E=\sqrt{m_0^2c^2+p^2c^4}$$but when I plug this into MMa, I get multiple answers:
$$Solve[E^2=m_0^2c^2+p^2c^4,E]$$ $$\left\{\left\{E=-\sqrt{m_0^2c^2+p^2c^4}\right\},\left\{E=\sqrt{m_0^2c^2+p^2c^4}\right\}\right\}$$How do I tell MMa that $m_0$, $c$ and $p$ are all real numbers - and therefore there is only one solution - so I don't have to guess at which of the two answers I should use in the next couple of equations?

Comment: `$Assumptions = And @@ Thread[{e, m0, p, c} >= 0]; Solve[e^2 == m0^2 c^2 + p^2 c^4 && $Assumptions, e] // Simplify`

Comment: Have a look at `Assuming`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch - `Solve` does not use the option `Assumptions` so `Assuming` by itself would have no effect. For `Solve` to use assumptions they must be included as constraints. Any subsequent `Simplify` could then use assumptions from an enclosing `Assuming`

Comment: @BobHanlon - Yes, that did it.  Thank you.

Comment: A quadratic equation has always two solutions, independently of the assumptions.

Comment: @yarchik - MMa would respectfully disagree with you.  Bob Hanlon's equation above has only one solution with the given assumptions.

Comment: @Quarkly There are two solutions, you just pick up one that satisfies your assumption. ;) If Bob Hanlon solution works for you, that is the only what counts.

Comment: @yarchik - Math is not my first language, but programming is, so I understand how functions work.  A quadratic equation has two solutions only when the expression inside the root is allowed to be negative.  If you remove that freedom, if you remove the possibility that the root term can be negative, then how do you get a negative solution?

Comment: @BobHanlon’s assumptions assume not just that the solutions are real, but that they are greater than or equal to 0. A quadratic with the appropriate discriminant indeed always has two *real* solutions, and the solutions given originally happen to both be real—just not both nonnegative. The other possibilities, of course, are that the quadratic has two complex nonreal roots, or that the quadratic has a single root of multiplicity 2 (i.e. that the quadratic is of the form $(x - c)^2$).

Comment: Note that the uses of a set of propositions $A$ as *assumptions* and as *conditions* are logically distinct uses, as $A \Rightarrow B$ (implication or "if-then") and as $A \wedge B$ (conjunction or "and"), respectively. @BobHanlon's suggestion uses $A$ in the latter sense as conditions or constraints, which is what is desired; but they are not used, strictly speaking, as *assumptions.* However, there is no need to use (or abuse?) the variable `$Assumptions` to achieve this. You could use your own variable `constraints` instead.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - the use of `$Assumptions` makes the assumptions automatically available to the `Simplify` and avoids the `ConditionalExpression` that explicitly reiterates the constraints.

Comment: @BobHanlon Quite right. I overlooked that in my comment. But it makes no difference in the output I get in V12.2. Both ways give the same `ConditionalExpression`, even with `FullSimplify`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - with version 12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020), `$Assumptions = And @@ Thread[{e, m0, p, c} >= 0]; Solve[e^2 == m0^2 c^2 + p^2 c^4 && $Assumptions, e] // Simplify` evaluates to `{{e -> c Sqrt[m0^2 + c^2 p^2]}}`

Comment: @BobHanlon Weird, I was accidentally in 12.1, in which it mysteriously failed. Works fine in V12.2 as expected. Sorry for the error.

Comment: @BobHanlon  `Simplify` seems to be unnecessary in V12.2. `Solve[e^2 == m0^2 c^2 + p^2 c^4, e, Assumptions -> And @@ Thread[{e, m0, p, c} > 0]]]` works just fine. No `ConditionalExpression`. This is because as of V12.2 `Solve` uses `$Assumptions` and has an `Assumptions` option. I knew of that change, but forgot it when I made my first comment.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - I also had forgotten about `Solve` now using `Assumptions`. Thanks for reminding me.